# undefined local variable or method `browse_path'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I'm getting this error

```
NameError in Browse#index
undefined local variable or method `browse_path'
```

Here's the code in view where the error is raised

```
<li><%= link_to "Browse",    browse_path %></li>
```

Here's the controller

```
class BrowseController < ApplicationController

def index
    @tags = tag.find(:all, :order => 'created_at DESC') 
end
end
```

and finally my routes

```
get'/browse' => 'browse#index', :as => :index
```

anyone know what is causing this?

Comment: When in doubt about what a path helper name is, run "rake routes" in your terminal and it will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `:as => :browse` for the named route.